# Program to check whether a string is accepted by an unrestricted grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

How can I write a program to find out whether a given string is generated using a type 0 grammar (unrestricted grammar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

Nobody can since the membership problem for unrestricted grammar is undecidable. Here is [a reference in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar#Computational_properties).

On the other hand, the membership problem for context-sensitive grammar or, what is equivalent, [noncontracting grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar) is decidable. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Computational_problems)

Just in case it is not clear to you, a collection of decision problems (a.k.a, yes/no questions) is decidable if there is a program which will solve any given one of them correctly within finitely many steps. It is undecidable if there is not such a program. 
The existence of undecidable problems could be the best technical backdrop for [this story](https://xkcd.com/1831/).

You will learn its formal definition in your study of computer science (or you might have). There will be **lots of undecidable problems** coming to you; so if you suspect one, you should probably wait until you have studied the chapter about undecidability and somewhat more before you raise a similar question. Or you could just search around using the keyword "decidable" or "undecidable"

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **no, it's proven impossible**.

Slightly longer answer: unrestricted grammars are equivalent in power to Turing machines. That is, you can convert any Turing machine to an unrestricted grammar without loss of generality.

It's famously impossible to decide whether an arbitrary Turing machine accepts an arbitrary string (see the Halting Problem and Rice's Theorem). If you could decide whether an unrestricted grammar produced a given string, you could convert any Turing machine into an unrestricted grammar, and decide whether it accepted—and that's impossible. Therefore, you can't decide whether an unrestricted grammar produces a given string, in the general case.